# docker-py client.images.list() always shows all images

Tags: python, docker, dockerpy

I'm not able to filter images from client.images.list()

https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/images.html#docker.models.images.ImageCollection.list

The documentation says *"name (str) – Only show images belonging to the repository name"*

`client.images.list(name="elixir")`

**EXPECTATION:**

```
[<Image: 'elixir:1.10-alpine'>]
```

**ACTUAL:**

```
[<Image: 'postgres:latest'>, <Image: 'node:15-alpine'>, <Image: 'elixir:1.10-alpine'>, <Image: 'nginx:stable-alpine'>]
```

Bug?

Versions:

Docker version 20.10.0, build 7287ab3

```
>>> import docker
>>> docker.__version__
'4.4.0'
```

Comment: sure you don't have those images? checked?

Comment: what repo are you connected to? etc

Comment: what does `docker images` or `docker image ls` say?

Comment: @Paul 
I have all the images in the ACTUAL. However, I would expect client.list(name) to only give images with the repository == name. The docker client is only from_env().

Comment: @Martin,
`docker images` shows the same images as ACTUAL. i.e. all the images on my local registry.

Comment: @snakajim this just is not working.  The client builds a dict `{'filter': 'yacht', 'only_ids':0, 'all': 0}` and passes it to the docker api (I called `client.image.list(name='yacht')`).  Looks like a docker api issue, not the SDK.

Answer (score 2):

I had to use:-

```
client.images.list(filters = { "reference" : "elixir:1.10-alpine"})
```

To return a list of images, Martins response appears to be missing the 's' off images

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You basically copied Martin's answer and fixed a type in that. Rather than posting your "own" answer, just comment on Martin's one.

Comment: I could not comment on Martin's answer, it said I need 50 rep points. Creating a new answer was the only option I had, other than not commenting at all. I will take option 2 next time.

Comment: You could always suggest an edit.

Answer (score 1):

`client.images.list(filters = { "reference" : "elixir:1.10-alpine"})` will give you what you want.

I used https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#operation/ImageList as the source of my inspiration.

Comment: its client.imgaes , not image. a small typo :)